# Cordova iOS does not open map from geo link

Tags: android, ios, cordova, google-maps, ionic-framework

I am developing hybrid app using Cordova & Ionic. At first I develop for Android. My app contains `geo:` and `tel:` link. On Android, everything works fine. `geo:` link will open up Google Map or Waze, and `tel:` link will open phone call.

However, on iOS the `tel:` link still work, but the `geo:` link does not work. When I click on it, nothing happen. When I look at Xcode, it says: `Failed to load webpage with error: The URL can’t be shown`

How can I fix it?

Comment: there is no geo url scheme on ios, google maps website url should open google maps app, and apple maps website url or maps:// scheme should open apple maps app

Comment: @jcesarmobile thanks for your comment. So, I just need to replace `geo:` to `maps://` and it will works?

Comment: @jcesarmobile Tried with `maps:`, doesn't work either.... Can you please show some example for better understanding? Thank you.

Comment: which cordova version are you using? I've just tried on a fresh cordova project and it works fine ```<a href="maps://?ll=1.5149818510303,110.35436153412&q=test">map link</a>``` https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/featuredarticles/iPhoneURLScheme_Reference/MapLinks/MapLinks.html

Answer (score 1):

On iOS you need to use "maps:"

On Android you can use "geo:" or "http://maps.google.com/maps"

In both cases, you'll probably need the [inappbrowser](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/reference/cordova-plugin-inappbrowser/) pluing

```
var url = "http://maps.google.com/maps"; 
if (device.platform.toLowerCase() == "ios") {   
  url = "maps:" 
} 
url + "?q=1.5149818510303,110.35436153412";
```

Then add the map link with `target="_system"`, this signals to the `inappbrowser` plugin to open it externally.

```
<a href="{{ url }}" target="_system">map link</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

I've write a method that replace all geo: href on devices that is different of android. In android the geo: tag runs better than open google maps directly because its fire an option to open Waze, Uber, Google Maps and other maps applications.

With cordova device plugin run:

```
if(device.platform.toLowerCase != 'android'){
    $('a').each(function(i,el){
        if($(el).attr('href').indexOf("geo:") == 0){
            $(el).attr(
                'href',
                $(el).attr('href').replace(
                    'geo:',
                    'http://maps.google.com/maps?q='
                )
            );
        }
    });
}
```